# How Can I Compress Images Before Uploading to Firebase?

Tags: android, image, firebase, compression

I am creating a social network application in which users can post images, so when a user uploads its image, it is of very large size and when I am retrieving that image, it is taking too much time with Picasso.
Is there any way to compress those images before uploading without significant quality loss, so that they can be retrieved very efficiently and fast.
P.S: I am using Firebase as a backend Server.

Here is my code of uploading images.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        ImageUri = data.getData();
        SelectPostImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

final StorageReference filePath = PostImagesRef.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

    final UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(ImageUri);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            String message = e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Some Error Occured"+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    downloadImageUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                    return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        downloadImageUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Saved To Database Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SavingPostInformationToDatabase();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Please help me. Any Help or Suggestion Would Be Appreciable.
Thanks In Advance.!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple using Glide to resize your image and using that image to upload to firebase

```
Glide.with(requireActivity())
                .asBitmap()
                .override(YOUR_IMAGE_SIZE, YOUR_IMAGE_SIZE)
                .load(uri)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {

                        // using bitmapToByte(resource) -> byte
                        // using filePath.putBytes(data) -> uploadTask
                         val filePath = PostImagesRef.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg")

                         val uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(bitmapToByte(resource))
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                        // some other reason.
                        // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                        // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
                    }
                })
```

`bitmapToByte` function

```
 fun bitmapToByte(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

hope this helps